# wordpress how change media frame modal feature image to choose image

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

i'm try to change label set feature image and remove feature image with `str_replace` php, but how to change in modal media frame?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [media_view_strings hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_view_strings/):

```
add_filter( 'media_view_strings', 'so_45136011_change_featured_image_title', 10, 2 );
function so_45136011_change_featured_image_title( $strings,  $post ){
    $strings['setFeaturedImageTitle'] = __( 'My new title' );
    return $strings;
}
```